# change Dom elements to be invisible

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to make the variables "answer" and "submit" invisible and I tried to do that on lines 21-22 in the javascript file but it doesn't work
how can I make them invisible ?

**javascript and html code:**

```js
let question = document.getElementById("question");
let answer = document.getElementById("answer");
let submit = document.getElementById("submit");

//create an array of questions
let questions = ["What type of file do you need to open javascript file ?", "question 2", "question 3", "question 4", "question 5", "question 6", "question 7", "question 8", "question 9", "question 10"];

//create an array of answers
let answers = ["js", "answer 2", "answer 3", "answer 4", "answer 5", "answer 6", "answer 7", "answer 8", "answer 9", "answer 10"];

// set the question varible to the first question in the array
let questionNumber = 0;
question.innerText = questions[questionNumber];

let points = 0;
let counter = 0;

submit.addEventListener("click", function(){
    if(counter == questions.length - 1){
        question.innerText = "You got " + points + " out of " + questions.length * 10 + " points";
        answer.style.display = "none";
        submit.style.display = "none";
    }
    answer = document.getElementById("answer").value;
    if(answer == answers[questionNumber]){
        points +=10;
        console.log("correct");
    }   
    else{
        console.log("incorrect" + " " + "the correct answer is " + answers[questionNumber]);
        if(points < 10){
            points = 0;
        }
        else{
            points -= 10;
        }
    }
    //in the else I check if the user have more than 10 points and if so I decrement the points by 10 but id no then I set the points to 0
    questionNumber++;
    counter++;
    question.innerText = questions[questionNumber];
});
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <span id="question"></span>
    <div class="input-group flex-nowrap">
      <input type="text" id="answer" class="form-control" placeholder="Answer Here..." aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="addon-wrapping">
    </div>
    <button type="button" id="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success">Submit</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by making variables invisible?

Comment: I want to change their visibility, or change the display to none but its not working

Comment: Variables don't have visiblity, DOM elements do.

Comment: The problem is that you reused the variable `answer`: `answer = document.getElementById("answer").value;` Now it contains the user's answer instead of the DOM element, so you can't make it invisible.

Comment: Just use different variables and you'll be fine.

Comment: what about the submit button ?

Comment: What about it? You never reuse the variable `submit`, so it's fine.

Answer (score 1):

The element selection variables should be set as `const` because the elements don't change only their content does. This would prevent mistakes as you had in your code, which is stated in the next paragraph.

In event listener function I changed the `answer` variable to `answerValue` because you cant change a `const` set to the element. So you need to store that data into a different name. In your code you were trying to call the style property on a value and not the element. This is because you changed the answer from the element to the value on each call of the function.

```js
const question = document.getElementById("question");
const answer = document.getElementById("answer");
const submit = document.getElementById("submit");

//create an array of questions
let questions = ["What type of file do you need to open javascript file ?", "question 2", "question 3", "question 4", "question 5", "question 6", "question 7", "question 8", "question 9", "question 10"];

//create an array of answers
let answers = ["js", "answer 2", "answer 3", "answer 4", "answer 5", "answer 6", "answer 7", "answer 8", "answer 9", "answer 10"];

// set the question varible to the first question in the array
let questionNumber = 0;
question.innerText = questions[questionNumber];

let points = 0;
let counter = 0;

submit.addEventListener("click", function () {
    if (counter == questions.length - 1) {
        question.innerText = "You got " + points + " out of " + questions.length * 10 + " points";
        answer.style.display = "none";
        submit.style.display = "none";
    }
    // here I changed it to call the answer element and get its value and store it into "answerValue" instead of replacing the answer element.
    const answerValue = answer.value;
    if (answerValue == answers[questionNumber]) {
        points += 10;
        console.log("correct");
    }
    else {
        console.log("incorrect" + " " + "the correct answer is " + answers[questionNumber]);
        if (points < 10) {
            points = 0;
        }
        else {
            points -= 10;
        }
    }
    //in the else I check if the user have more than 10 points and if so I decrement the points by 10 but id no then I set the points to 0
    questionNumber++;
    counter++;
    question.innerText = questions[questionNumber];
});
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <span id="question"></span>
    <div class="input-group flex-nowrap">
      <input type="text" id="answer" class="form-control" placeholder="Answer Here..." aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="addon-wrapping">
    </div>
    <button type="button" id="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success">Submit</button>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

After `answer = document.getElementById("answer").value;` you have to set the display to none, or you can use visibility to hidden

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).